# ADBannerView error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:)

Tags: ios, runtime-error, iad

My app is on the App Store and it doesn't show any ad. So, after contacting Apple and receiving no solution, I saw this error in the console while running my app on the simulator:

```
[AppDeveloper] ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=1 "Service session terminated." UserInfo=0x7f18e160 {ADInternalErrorCode=1002, NSLocalizedDescription=Service session terminated.}
```

Is that the reason why my app doesn't show any ads and just shows a white space where the `ADBannerView` is?

Comment: well, given the error it's probably a good place to start. you could also just be getting an error trying to load the ad and this exception is thrown to let you know that there's nothing that's intercepting that error.

Comment: That error is not the reason why ads are not shown. I don't know what the reason is, it might be simply because there are no ads available at the moment for your app (fill rate is not always 100%). That is why you need to implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError to handle this case. For example, you can hide the banner so that your users don't see empty white rectangular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't included the `ADBannerView`'s delegate methods. I've commented the parts you may be missing from your code.

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface ViewController () <ADBannerViewDelegate> // Have you included this?

@end

@implementation ViewController {
    // Your iAd Banner
    ADBannerView *iAdView;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Setup iAd view
    iAdView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    iAdView.delegate = self; // And have you done this?

    [iAdView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, iAdView.bounds.size.width, iAdView.bounds.size.height)];
    iAdView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height - (iAdView.bounds.size.height / 2));
    [self.view addSubview:iAdView];
    iAdView.alpha = 0.0;
}

// And have you included these delegate methods to handle when an ad is received or not?
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    NSLog(@"iAd received ad");
    // display ad
    iAdView.alpha = 1.0;
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"iAd failed");
    // Hide ad
    iAdView.alpha = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after a week without ads appearing in my app today they just appeared so that means that the code is ok