# Why is a blank rectangle showing on my App where the iAd should be?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, iad

I've recently released my app and am having troubles with viewing the iAd. It comes up as a blank white rectangle, despite in the testing phase the 'You're Connected with iAd' appears. It appears in the iAd sales analytic section and says 'Live: This app is receiving live ads' yet all it is showing is a white rectangle

Is there a step I would've missed in implementing iAd?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you did not implement your `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` delegate method. You need to hide or move your `ADBannerView` off screen when there is no ad to show. iAd does not always have an ad to present. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28708573/2108547) for a quick example.